# How to update path of flutter in macos?

Tags: flutter, macos, terminal

Hey I just installed flutter and did everything as in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U4TJ5ITGe5Y and also as told on the website: https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/macos#update-your-path.

To update the path of flutter I put this command in the [.zshrc file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHa45.png).

```
export PATH="$PATH:[PATH_OF_FLUTTER_GIT_DIRECTORY]/bin"
```

However it doesn't work. Does anybody have an idea what I could be doing wrong?

Thanks a lot and have a nice day!

Comment: you gotta replace [PATH_OF_FLUTTER_GIT_DIRECTORY] with the path to the flutter  sdk you downloaded

Comment: I know and I already did that, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully this helps...

1. Open up your terminal by pressing cmd and space, then typing terminal.
2. enter the command -   vim ~/.shrc
3. Then you want to press i to edit text
4. then enter 'export PATH="$PATH:`pwd`/flutter/bin"'   (without the ''), pwd = is the path where the flutter folder is found e.g. user/desktop/.

However in most cases the pwd is $HOME /desktop  in which cases the command should look like this in the terminal

export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/Deskop/flutter/bin".   - in this cases my flutter folder is on my desktop

5. Press Esc then and enter the command  :wq!
   and done

Comment: I did this and it is still not working. Do you know if it is important to access flutter from every terminal window? Because I am able to set the path for the current terminal window only. After I close the window I have to set the path again, but this way I am able to run flutter doctor for example.

Comment: No that isn't necessary, usually adding it once is enough, can you say what Mac OS you are currently running?

Comment: macos monterey, 12.3.1 on an M1 macbook

Comment: I don't know exactly what I did different this time, but now I got it. Maybe my mistake was to not close the terminal and start it again. I think I tried that before, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 11):

Adding FLUTTER PATH to the terminal permanently

**Step:1**

TYPE:  `echo $SHELL`

- This will tell which SHELL you are using (bash or Z shell)

**Step:2**

TYPE: `$HOME/.bashrc`

- If it shows ***file does not exists***, then you need to create new zshrc file

(Only if the above error occurs) TYPE:  `touch ~/.zshrc`      // this will create a new zshrc file

**Step 3:**

TYPE: `open  $HOME/.zshrc`  //to open the **zshrc** file

- Add the flutter bin path for setting to the terminal permanently in **zshrc** file

TYPE: `export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/development/flutter/bin"`

**Step 4:**

TYPE:  `source $HOME/.zshrc` //to refresh the current terminal window

Now u can run flutter cmds without adding a path at all times

Comment: Worked. Thank you very much

Comment: This should be marked as answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Apple Silicon and macOS Ventura, you can follow these steps:

1. Open Terminal.
2. Use the following command to open the `.zshrc` file in the nano text editor:

> **`nano .zshrc`**

3. Add the Flutter path to the file by appending the following line:

> **export PATH="$PATH:/Users/{your_flutter_extracted_path}/bin"**

4. Save the changes by pressing `CTRL + O`, then exit Nano by pressing `CTRL + X`.
5. To verify that the path has been added successfully, run the following command in the Terminal:

> **which flutter**

It should display the path to Flutter similar to this:

> **/Users/{your_flutter_extracted_path}/bin/flutter**

If you see the correct Flutter path, you are all set and ready to use Flutter on your Apple Silicon macOS Ventura setup!